# Owin Selfhosted web api not reaching api controllers/actions

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, integration-testing, owin, self-hosting

I've started with a tutorial http://www.strathweb.com/2013/12/owin-memory-integration-testing/, and everything works just fine, but when I do the same steps to my real prject, I get StatusCode 500 that says (Internal server error) in response. When I tried to debugg the api, I realized that it's not even reaching the api controllers or actions. here is what I'm doing starting with the Startup class:

```
    public class OwinStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "Api/{controller}/{id}",
                                        new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
            config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
   }
```

then I'm trying to get entities by doing this:

```
using (TestServer server = TestServer.Create<OwinStartup>())
            {
            server.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/");
            var response = server.HttpClient.GetAsync("Api/controllerName").Result;
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<EntityModel>().Result;
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            }
```

When I browse the link I'm setting (http://localhost/api/controllerName) I get the values I want to get (in the browser) but it's using the IIS then. In my case I want to use the OWIN testServer. I turned IIS off and ran my test but still the same response. As I said I'm jsut following the tutorial and nothing more. 
This is what I'm getting:[image]
Do i need to make something like OwinMiddleware thing? or I'm I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the response header that contains the 500 error, what is the detail of the error.

Comment: @jolySoft images added to the question.

Comment: Have you tried everything in here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

Comment: @jolySoft still the same problem

Comment: I know I keep asking question but I'm just trying to get to the real issue.  What is the content of the response.  Somewhere in what you get back from the server will be the detail of the issue.  As you know http 500 error covers loads so without that detail it's very hard to try and help

Comment: I think you try to troubleshoot multiple thing in one. first, write a command line program, with your code of startup, next use postman to hit your endpoint, put a breakpoint in your controller, see what you are getting and what you are returning. you are getting 500, so that means the server is running and your endpoint is hit.